# Is it possible to compress LESS CSS files with htaccess? (and how to?)

Tags: css, .htaccess, compression, less

I'm using less css in my project, and YSlow is telling me that my .less files are nod GZip compressed.

All my other files (js, html, and event CSS files if I include some...) are well encoded, but not LESS files.

Here is my .htaccess :

```
# Apache configuration file
# httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

# Note .htaccess files are an overhead, this logic should be in your Apache config if possible
# httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

# Techniques in here adapted from all over, including:
#   Kroc Camen: camendesign.com/.htaccess
#   perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/
#   Sample .htaccess file of CMS MODx: modxcms.com


###
### If you run a webserver other than Apache, consider:
### github.com/h5bp/server-configs
###



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
#  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|less|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cross-domain AJAX requests
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve cross-domain Ajax requests, disabled by default.
# enable-cors.org
# code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

#  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#  </IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
# developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
# blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
# hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
# wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


# CSS
AddType text/css         css less

# JavaScript
#   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
#   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
AddType application/javascript         js

# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm

# SVG
#   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

# Assorted types
AddType image/x-icon                        ico
AddType image/webp                          webp
AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component                    htc
AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow concatenation from within specific js and css files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# e.g. Inside of script.combined.js you could have
#   <!--#include file="libs/jquery-1.5.0.min.js" -->
#   <!--#include file="plugins/jquery.idletimer.js" -->
# and they would be included into this single file.

# This is not in use in the boilerplate as it stands. You may
# choose to name your files in this way for this advantage or
# concatenate and minify them manually.
# Disabled by default.

#<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
#  Options +Includes
#  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
#  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
#  Options +Includes
#  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
#  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
#</FilesMatch>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
  <IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
    # Legacy versions of Apache
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with cachebusting query params like
#   <script src="application.js?20100608">
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS  and JS to something like
#   "access plus 1 week" or so.

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ETag removal
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
# static content.
#   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers - in
# combination with the "ExpiresByType" rules for images (see above). If
# needed, un-comment the following rules.

BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cookie setting from iframes
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow cookies to be set from iframes (for IE only)
# If needed, uncomment and specify a path or regex in the Location directive

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   <Location />
#     Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""
#   </Location>
# </IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The same content should never be available under two different URLs - especially not with and
# without "www." at the beginning, since this can cause SEO problems (duplicate content).
# That's why you should choose one of the alternatives and redirect the other one.

# By default option 1 (no "www.") is activated. Remember: Shorter URLs are sexier.
# no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b

# If you rather want to use option 2, just comment out all option 1 lines
# and uncomment option 2.
# IMPORTANT: NEVER USE BOTH RULES AT THE SAME TIME!

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 1:
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Option 2:
# To rewrite "example.com -> www.example.com" uncomment the following lines.
# Be aware that the following rule might not be a good idea if you
# use "real" subdomains for certain parts of your website.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Built-in filename-based cache busting
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# If you're not using the build script to manage your filename version revving,
# you might want to consider enabling this, which will route requests for
# /css/style.20110203.css to /css/style.css

# To understand why this is important and a better idea than all.css?v1231,
# read: github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Version-Control-with-Cachebusting

# Uncomment to enable.
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
# </IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent SSL cert warnings
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent
# https://www.example.com when your cert only allows https://secure.example.com
# Uncomment the following lines to use this feature.

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#   RewriteRule ^ https://example-domain-please-change-me.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent 404 errors for non-existing redirected folders
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# without -MultiViews, Apache will give a 404 for a rewrite if a folder of the same name does not exist
#   e.g. /blog/hello : webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm

Options -MultiViews



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Custom 404 page
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# You can add custom pages to handle 500 or 403 pretty easily, if you like.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .css .less .js .xml .json .rss .atom



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# A little more security
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


# Do we want to advertise the exact version number of Apache we're running?
# Probably not.
## This can only be enabled if used in httpd.conf - It will not work in .htaccess
# ServerTokens Prod


# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a default document
# Usually you should leave this activated, because you shouldn't allow everybody to surf through
# every folder on your server (which includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>


# Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
# includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>


# Block access to backup and source files
# This files may be left by some text/html editors and
# pose a great security danger, when someone can access them
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>


# If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
# should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
# This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
# scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
#
# IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS :
#
# Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
# case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
# using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
# doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
# include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
# reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
# information about setting PHP directives.

php_flag register_globals Off

# Rename session cookie to something else, than PHPSESSID
php_value session.name sid

# Do not show you are using PHP
# Note: Move this line to php.ini since it won't work in .htaccess
php_flag expose_php Off

# Level of log detail - log all errors
php_value error_reporting -1

# Write errors to log file
php_flag log_errors On

# Do not display errors in browser (production - Off, development - On)
php_flag display_errors On

# Do not display startup errors (production - Off, development - On)
php_flag display_startup_errors On

# Format errors in plain text
# Note: Leave this setting 'On' for xdebug's var_dump() output
php_flag html_errors On

# Show multiple occurrence of error
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors Off

# Show same errors from different sources
php_flag ignore_repeated_source Off

# Size limit for error messages
php_value log_errors_max_len 1024

# Don't precede error with string (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
php_value error_prepend_string " "

# Don't prepend to error (doesn't accept empty string, use whitespace if you need)
php_value error_append_string " "

# Increase cookie security
<IfModule php5_module>
  php_value session.cookie_httponly true
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you using a local less css file or from a distant repository ?

Comment: Are you serving *.less files and transforming with javaScript? In that case wouldn´t a much higher performance gain be to transform them server side and only serve css files?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, and sorry for not being more responsive... True, it would be much more efficient, but still I was wondering...

Comment: Does your frontend actually use the `.less` files? If you only want to export the source for debugging purpose, you could generate source maps instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330996/webpack-4-how-to-get-css-source-maps-working-with-less