# Webpack 4: How to get CSS source maps working with LESS?

Tags: css, webpack, less, webpack-4

I've been trying for years now to get CSS sourcemaps to work in webpack to no avail. I'm not sure where in the chain things are going awry. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's what's happening:

[image]

The line numbers are wrong, and actually the filenames are wrong too. `main.less` just contains a bunch of `@import`s, the actual CSS is in a different file.

Below is my `webpack.config.js`. I've printed it with `util.inspect` because it's combined from a lot of different chunks, and I think it's easier to read this way:

```
{ target: 'web',
  context: '/home/me/Projects/myproject',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: 
   { main: 
      [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets/scripts/lib/autofocus-polyfill',
        '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets/scripts/lib/matches-polyfill',
        'whatwg-fetch',
        'core-js/es6',
        'core-js/stage/4',
        '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets/main' ],
     print: 
      [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets/stylesheets/print' ] },
  output: 
   { path: '/home/me/Projects/myproject/www/assets',
     pathinfo: false,
     publicPath: '/assets/',
     crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous',
     filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
     chunkFilename: 'chunk.[chunkhash].js' },
  resolve: 
   { modules: 
      [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets',
        '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/',
        '/home/me/Projects/myproject/vendor/' ],
     alias: 
      { 'jquery-ui/ui/widget': '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/jquery-ui/widget.js' },
     extensions: [ '.jsx', '.js', '.less', '.css' ] },
  node: { __filename: true, __dirname: true, fs: 'empty' },
  amd: { jQuery: true },
  module: 
   { rules: 
      [ { enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          include: '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets',
          options: { cache: false, quiet: true, failOnError: true } },
        { test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'strip-loader',
          options: 
           { strip: 
              [ 'console.assert',
                'console.count',
                'console.dir',
                'console.dirxml',
                'console.group',
                'console.groupCollapsed',
                'console.groupEnd',
                'console.info',
                'console.log',
                'console.profile',
                'console.profileEnd',
                'console.table',
                'console.time',
                'console.timeEnd',
                'console.timeStamp' ] } },
        { test: /\.less$/,
          use: 
           [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
             { loader: 'css-loader',
               options: 
                { sourceMap: true,
                  root: '/home/me/Projects/myproject/www',
                  localIdentName: '[name]_[local]--[hash:base62:5]',
                  importLoaders: 1 } },
             { loader: 'postcss-loader',
               options: 
                { ident: 'postcss',
                  sourceMap: true,
                  plugins: [Function: plugins] } },
             { loader: 'less-loader',
               options: { sourceMap: true, strictMath: true, strictUnits: true } } ] },
        { test: /\.css$/,
          use: 
           [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
             { loader: 'css-loader',
               options: 
                { sourceMap: true,
                  root: '/home/me/Projects/myproject/www',
                  localIdentName: '[name]_[local]--[hash:base62:5]',
                  importLoaders: 1 } },
             { loader: 'postcss-loader',
               options: 
                { ident: 'postcss',
                  sourceMap: true,
                  plugins: [Function: plugins] } } ] },
        { test: /\.jsx?$/,
          include: 
           [ '/home/me/Projects/myproject/assets',
             '/home/me/Projects/myproject/node_modules/react-ajax-loader' ],
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: 
           { cacheDirectory: '/home/me/Projects/myproject/cache/babel',
             forceEnv: 'production' } },
        { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)($|\?)/i,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: { limit: 2048, name: '[name].[md5:hash:base32:10].[ext]' } },
        { test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|htc)($|\?)/i,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[md5:hash:base32:10].[ext]' } } ] },
  plugins: 
   [ NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin {},
     HashedModuleIdsPlugin {
       options: 
        { context: null,
          hashFunction: 'md4',
          hashDigest: 'base64',
          hashDigestLength: 4 } },
     LoaderOptionsPlugin { options: { options: {}, test: { test: [Function: test] } } },
     MiniCssExtractPlugin {
       options: 
        { filename: '[name].[hash].css',
          chunkFilename: 'chunk.[chunkhash].css' } },
     ProvidePlugin {
       definitions: 
        { '$': 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          timezoneJS: 'timezone-js',
          React: 'react',
          _: 'lodash' } },
     DefinePlugin {
       definitions: { 'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"production"' } } },
     { apply: [Function: apply] } ],
  bail: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: 
   { minimize: true,
     minimizer: 
      [ UglifyJsPlugin {
          options: 
           { test: /\.(js?)(\?.+)?$/i,
             warningsFilter: [Function],
             extractComments: /^!|\b(copyright|license)\b|@(preserve|license|cc_on)\b/i,
             sourceMap: true,
             cache: true,
             parallel: true,
             include: undefined,
             exclude: /\.min\.js$/,
             uglifyOptions: 
              { output: { beautify: false },
                compress: { warnings: false, drop_console: true },
                mangle: true,
                sourceMap: true } } } ],
     splitChunks: { chunks: 'all' },
     runtimeChunk: true } }
```

Somewhere in the middle there you can see the loaders for `.less`. Expanded out, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            root: publicDir,
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]--[hash:base62:5]',
            importLoaders: 1,
        }
    },
    {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            sourceMap: true,
            plugins: loader => [
                require('autoprefixer')({
                    browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 Firefox versions', 'last 2 Chrome versions', 'last 2 Edge versions', 'last 2 Safari versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'IE >= 8'],
                }),
                require('postcss-opacity'),
                require('cssnano')({
                    discardComments: {
                        remove: comment => !copyrightPatt.test(comment),
                    }
                })
            ],
        }
    },
    {
        loader: 'less-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            strictMath: true,
            strictUnits: true,
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, I've got 3 different loaders (css-loader, postcss-loader and less-loader). They all have `sourceMap` set to `true`, so the sourcemaps should carry back to the original source, right?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Actually, I still get a random source map even if I set all 3 of those loaders to `sourceMap: false`. Is `devtool` overriding their settings??

Answer (score 0):

when remove the cssnano, the maps seems reasonable, but not accuracy, and the config of mine is quiet simple.

```
.patent {        // line1
    .child {}    // map to line1
    .childs {}   // map to line1
}
```

Comment: Would you care to share your webpack config? I can't even get the right filenames to appear.